# Series with the smallest number whose square is divisible by $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

I was looking into this [sequence](https://oeis.org/A019554). And I'm particularly interested in the asymptotic behavior of the following series (which is stated on the site) $$\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{a(k)} \sim \frac{3(\log n)^2}{2\pi^2} + \cdots, $$ where $a(k) = \min\{m \in \mathbb{N}: k \mid m^2 \}$. But I couldn't find any further details about it on the site, except for the author [Vaclav Kotesovec](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Vaclav_Kotesovec), but with no success finding any further details about the series. Can you provide me with some relevant references, please?

Comment: see the first page of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.10568.pdf  for address

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find a reference, but (as noted in the OEIS page) if we have $k = a b^2$ with squarefree $a$ then $a(k) = ab$, so $$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\leq x}\frac1{a(k)}
&= \sum_{a b^2 \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(a)}{ab} = \sum_{a \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(a)}{a} \sum_{b^2 \leq x/a}\frac1b = \sum_{a \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(a) H_{\sqrt{x/a}}}{a}\\
&= \sum_{a \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(a) \left(\frac12\log(x) - \frac12\log(a) + \gamma + O(\sqrt{a/x})\right)}{a}\\
&= \left(\frac12\log(x) + \gamma\right) \sum_{a \leq x}\frac{\mu^2(a)}a - \frac12 \sum_{a \leq x}\frac{\mu^2(a)\log(a)}{a} + O(1).
\end{align*}$$

We have
$$\sum_{a \leq x}{\mu^2(a)} = \frac{6x}{\pi^2} + O(\sqrt x),$$
so by partial summation
$$\sum_{a \leq x}\frac{\mu^2(a)}a = \frac6{\pi^2}\log(x) + C + O\left(\frac1 {\sqrt x}\right),$$
and
$$\sum_{a \leq x}\frac{\mu^2(a) \log(a)}a = \frac{3}{\pi^2} \log^2(x) - \frac6{\pi^2} \log(x) + C_2 + O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}\right),$$
which gives the rough result. The more precise result can likely be found by directly looking at the sums (without passing through $\sum_{a \leq x}\mu^2(a)$) and using more terms for the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.